# EsLint /prettier giving unnecessary errors and providing auto adding paranthesis to the end of the expression

Tags: reactjs, typescript, prettier-vscode

I am using redux saga for asynchronous calls, I made an API call and store the data in local storage but eslint/prettier is auto adding parenthesis to assignment operator at the end of line. I don't find any relevant solution.

```js
function fetchData(services: requiredServices) {
  return function*() {
    try {
      let datafromlocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("studentInfo") || '{}');
      if (datafromlocalStorage && Object.keys(datafromlocalStorage).length < 1) {
        const { data } = yield call(services.dataManagement.getData);
        datafromlocalStorage = data;
        localStorage.setItem("studentInfo", JSON.stringify(data));
      }
      yield put(actions.saveContnet(datafromlocalStorage))
    } catch(e) {
    }
  }
}
```

It's giving error at the last line of try block, saying expression expected.

Comment: Please don't mix ESLint and prettier, they are two separate tools. Where exactly are parentheses added and by which of the tools? Also how did you configure ESLint?

Comment: The error "expression expected" usually is thrown when there is some kind of misconfiguration and ESLint cannot correctly parse the TypeScript code.

Answer (score 0):

The `catch` block is expecting at least one statement. If you just need to catch any thrown errors or rejected promises and don't care to handle them, then add a comment line, e.g `// ignored`.

```js
function fetchData(services: requiredServices) {
  return function*() {
    try {
      let datafromlocalStorage = JSON.parse(
        localStorage.getItem("studentInfo") || '{}'
      );
      if (datafromlocalStorage && 
        Object.keys(datafromlocalStorage).length < 1
      ) {
        const { data } = yield call(services.dataManagement.getData);
        datafromlocalStorage = data;
        localStorage.setItem("studentInfo", JSON.stringify(data));
      }
      yield put(actions.saveContnet(datafromlocalStorage));
    } catch {
      // ignored
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've triggerd an action to catch the errors. still it's giving error at last closing bracket of try block. it just works only when (datafromlocalStorage = data) wrapped under paranthesis after setting item in local storage. if I wrap like this jenkins build getting failed

Comment: @Sathish Sorry, are you saying that you *are* actually needing to handle caught errors? And that the code works when you let the formatter(s) rewrite `datafromlocalStorage = data;` as `(datafromlocalStorage = data;)`? Perhaps you should update your post to include your linter & prettier settings and a complete [mcve] of the code you are using. Please also include these details about the Jenkins build issue, there should be some build log output.